# Split strings in a matrix column and count the single elements in a new vector

Tags: r

I have a dataset like this from a file read into R with read.table():

```
Nr Result1
 1 "A203,A305,A409,B309,B424,B545"
 2 "A190,A203,A305,B309,B425,B545"
 3 "A203,A305,A410,B280,B309,B425,B545"
```

Result1 is a string that I would like to split at the "," to count the occurrence of each element in each row. 
I would like to count the different elements and write out the result in this format:

```
A190 A203 A305 A409 A410 B280 B309 B424 B425 B545
1    3    3    1    1    1    3    1    2    3
```

My first thought is to loop over every row, split the string into single elements, create a vector with the first set of elements and for the second row, check if matching element already exists (count+1) or append unknown element to vector with count=1.

I am quite new to R and would appreciate some example code or hints how to implement the single steps with R functions!
Many Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
newvector <- table(unlist(strsplit(as.character(df$Result1), ",")))
```

Result (stored in `newvector`):

```
#>newvector
#A190 A203 A305 A409 A410 B280 B309 B424 B425 B545 
#   1    3    3    1    1    1    3    1    2    3
```

The `strsplit` function splits the vector of strings (Result1) at each comma. The result is a list for each row of your data.frame (`df` in my example). To turn this list into a vector you use `unlist`. The `table` function then creates a table with the frequencies.

Comment: My upvote is only provisional. You _should_ wrap `as.character` around `df$Result1`

Comment: @BondedDust thanks, I updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Might be time to change your username to *inteRmediate* ;)

Comment: @RichardScriven I'll consider that :)

Comment: Thanks for this quick answer, it worked perfectly for me. Nice to see how responsive this forum is!

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative to consider:

The [development version of my "splitstackshape" package](https://github.com/mrdwab/splitstackshape/tree/devel) has a function called `concat.split.expanded` that "expands" values to their relevant column position in binary representation. You can then drop the first column and take the column sums (using `colSums`).

Here's some sample data:

```
mydf <- data.frame(Nr = 1:3,
                   Result1 = c("A190,A203,A305,B309,B425,B545", 
                               "A203,A305,A409,B309,B424,B545", 
                               "A203,A305,A410,B280,B309,B425,B545"))
```

And here's the implementation I would recommend:

```
## library(devtools)
## install_github("splitstackshape", "mrdwab", ref = "devel")
library(splitstackshape) ## Install "devel" version from github
colSums(concat.split.expanded(mydf, "Result1", ",", type="character", 
                              fill=0, drop = TRUE)[-1])
# Result1_A190 Result1_A203 Result1_A305 Result1_A409 Result1_A410 Result1_B280 
#            1            3            3            1            1            1 
# Result1_B309 Result1_B424 Result1_B425 Result1_B545 
#            3            1            2            3
```

In the long run, this will actually be faster than `table`:

```
mydf <- do.call(rbind, replicate(30000, mydf, FALSE))
dim(mydf)
# [1] 90000     2

fun1 <- function() {
  colSums(concat.split.expanded(mydf, "Result1", ",", 
                                type="character", fill=0, drop = TRUE)[-1])
} 
fun2 <- function() table(unlist(strsplit(as.character(mydf$Result1), ",")))
system.time(out1 <- fun1())
#    user  system elapsed 
#    6.10    0.00    6.09 
system.time(out2 <- fun2())
#    user  system elapsed 
#    0.77    0.00    0.76 
all.equal(as.vector(out1), as.vector(out2))
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks for your alternative, I will definitely come back to this solution once my R scripting becomes more serious!

Answer (score 0):

use table(unlist(strsplit(yourstring, ",")))
Example:
if your string is example = "A203,A305,A409,B309,B424,B545", the code below will produce:

```
R:> example = "A203,A305,A409,B309,B424,B545"
R:> table(unlist(strsplit(example, ",")))

A203 A305 A409 B309 B424 B545 
 1    1    1    1    1    1
```

A more complete example would be:

```
R:> ex <- data.frame(rbind(c(1, "A203,A305,A409,B309,B424,B545"), 
                           c(2, "A190,A203,A305,B309,B425,B545"),  
                           c(3, "A203,A305,A410,B280,B309,B425,B545")))
R:> ex
  X1                                 X2
1  1      A203,A305,A409,B309,B424,B545
2  2      A190,A203,A305,B309,B425,B545
3  3 A203,A305,A410,B280,B309,B425,B545
R:> names(ex) <- c("Nr", "Result1")
R:> ex
  Nr                            Result1
1  1      A203,A305,A409,B309,B424,B545
2  2      A190,A203,A305,B309,B425,B545
3  3 A203,A305,A410,B280,B309,B425,B545

R:> typeof(ex$Nr)
[1] "integer"
R:> typeof(ex$Result1)
[1] "integer"
R:> ex$Result1 <- as.character(ex$Result1)
R:> ex
  Nr                            Result1
1  1      A203,A305,A409,B309,B424,B545
2  2      A190,A203,A305,B309,B425,B545
3  3 A203,A305,A410,B280,B309,B425,B545
R:> table(unlist(strsplit(ex$Result[1], ",")))

A203 A305 A409 B309 B424 B545 
   1    1    1    1    1    1
```

Use sapply() for the entire column (Result1), all at once. See bellow.

```
R:> sapply(ex$Result1, function(x) {table(unlist(strsplit(x, ",")))})
$`A203,A305,A409,B309,B424,B545`

A203 A305 A409 B309 B424 B545 
  1    1    1    1    1    1 

$`A190,A203,A305,B309,B425,B545`

A190 A203 A305 B309 B425 B545 
  1    1    1    1    1    1 

$`A203,A305,A410,B280,B309,B425,B545`

A203 A305 A410 B280 B309 B425 B545 
  1    1    1    1    1    1    1
```