# Count elements in dataframe column, then create separate columns in R

Tags: r, count, tidyr, tidyverse

I am struggling for a few days with a solution myself. Hope you can help.
I checked the following already:

- [Counting the number of elements with the values of x in a vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1923273/counting-the-number-of-elements-with-the-values-of-x-in-a-vector)
- [Split strings in a matrix column and count the single elements in a new vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23642547/split-strings-in-a-matrix-column-and-count-the-single-elements-in-a-new-vector)
- http://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/separate.html
- [Count of Comma separate values in r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35264422/count-of-comma-separate-values-in-r)

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
df<-list(column=c("apple juice,guava-peach juice,melon apple juice","orange juice,pineapple strawberry lemon juice"))
df<-data.frame(df)
```

I want to separate each element separated by **","** in its own column. Number of columns must be based on the maximum number of elements in each row in **column**

```
 column1               column2                              column3
 apple juice       guava-peach juice                  melon apple juice
 orange juice    pineapple strawberry lemon juice             NA
```

I tried using

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)

#want to calculate number of columns needed and the sequence 

x<-str_count(df$column)

results<-df%>%separate(column,x,",")
```

Unfortunately I am not getting what I wish to.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: `x <- max(str_count(df$column, ",")) + 1 ; df %>% separate(column, paste0("column_", 1:x) ,",")`

Comment: @DavidArenburg This works perfectly, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean this?

```
library(splitstackshape)
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  cSplit("column", ",")
```

**Output is:**

```
       column_1                         column_2          column_3
1:  apple juice                guava-peach juice melon apple juice
2: orange juice pineapple strawberry lemon juice              <NA>
```

**Sample data:**

```
df <- structure(list(column = structure(1:2, .Label = c("apple juice,guava-peach juice,melon apple juice", 
"orange juice,pineapple strawberry lemon juice"), class = "factor")), .Names = "column", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Wow this is great :)

Comment: Glad that it helped :)

Comment: How can I add these results to existing dataframe (df)? Thank you

Comment: `df <- df %>% cSplit("column", ",")`